# Cannot override globally defined InputBindings locally with NotACommand

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inputbinding

I'm currently having trouble working with WPF InputBindings. We have defined application level keyboard bindings, but there are some places where I wish to use the control's default behaviour, by setting that control's binding to `NotACommand`.

This doesn't seem to work (though overriding a control level binding with another command seems to work fine). Here's some sample code:

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public void OnStartup()
{
    var window = Application.Current.MainWindow.
    window.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(CommandA, Key.A, Modifiers.Control));
    window.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(CommandB, Key.Delete, Modifiers.None));
}
```

**SomeControl.xaml.cs**

```
public void OverrideBindings()
{
    // this invokes LocalCommand instead of CommandA
    this.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(LocalCommand, Key.A, Modifiers.Control));
    // this still invokes CommandB
    this.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(ApplicationCommands.NotACommand, Key.Delete, Modifiers.None));
}
```

Any thoughts, suggestions? Or is this completely the wrong approach?

Comment: _this isn't real code_

Comment: May I ask the reason behind the -1 ?

Comment: Anyone ?
I've tried all variations of clearing the the input binding, xaml, code-behind, behaviours, and still the command set at the application level is the one being invoked.

Only thing I can think of, is that "SomeControl" is being hosted by a TabControl. Do they swallow events ? I didn't they did.